# Gatling using JDBC feeder connecting to SQL Server with Windows Authentication throws error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: jdbc, gatling, scala-gatling

Learning from this [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/?highlight=jdbc#jdbc-feeder) , I tried to use Gatling JDBC feeder to grab data from our SQL Server with Windows Authentication.

I add this dependency in my POM.xml

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dev.code-n-roll.gatling/jdbc-gatling -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>dev.code-n-roll.gatling</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc-gatling_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling/gatling-jdbc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
  <artifactId>gatling-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

My connection string looks like this

```js
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

val databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://CentralSQLServer:1433;databaseName=CustomerDB;integratedSecurity=true"
```

I added `integratedSecurity=true` because the access method to the SQL server is using Windows Authentication, not using username & password.  This works fine when I use vanilla Java with JDBC.

Then I define the JDBC Feeder

```js
val mySQLFeeder = jdbcFeeder(databaseUrl, "", "", "SELECT * FROM [CustomerDB].[dbo].[Users]")
```

I put empty String in username and password sections , since I don't have it.

Running the Gatling test using `mvn gatling:test` , I see this error is thrown by Gatling

```html
02:05:29.920 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.gatling.core.feeder.SourceFeederBuilder$.apply(Lio/gatling/core/feeder/FeederSource;Lio/gatling/core/config/GatlingConfiguration;)Lio/gatling/core/feeder/SourceFeederBuilder;
    at io.gatling.jdbc.Predef$.jdbcFeeder(Predef.scala:26)
    at testCases.Delete.<init>(Delete.scala:49)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:74)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:60)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:46)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:74)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:60)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:46)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.gatling.core.feeder.SourceFeederBuilder$.apply(Lio/gatling/core/feeder/FeederSource;Lio/gatling/core/config/GatlingConfiguration;)Lio/gatling/core/feeder/SourceFeederBuilder;
    at io.gatling.jdbc.Predef$.jdbcFeeder(Predef.scala:26)
    at testCases.Delete.<init>(Delete.scala:49)
    ... 16 more
```

It looks like Gatling JDBCFeeder method complains about my connection string using `integratedSecurity=true` since in the documentation we should use username and password. The thing is there are no username and password in my case.

Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: This (`NoSuchMethodError`) sounds very much an issue with dependency versions. `jdbc-gatling` `2.3.0` depends on Gatling 3.2.1 and you're using a Gatling 3.4.2 JAR.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it is related. `jdbc-gatling_2.12` is completely different package (3rd party extension as described here https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/). I just removed it from my POM.xml since I don't use it at all. The same error is still thrown. The jdbcFeeder that I am using comes from `gatling-jdbc io.gatling`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung is completely correct here (BTW, it's really a pity you didn't provided all the information on the official Gatling community mailing list, in particular your actual stacktrace). This NoSuchMethodError happens because your gatling-jdbc version is not aligned with your gatling-core one. You should check mvn dependency:tree.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GeorgeLeung and @StephaneLandelle .

The issue is caused by dependency version conflict.
The gatling-jdbc version must align with the gatling-core version.

Change the dependencies in POM.xml to this below does solve the issue.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.3.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.0.5</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.3.1</scala-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <scala.version>2.12.10</scala.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The `gatling-app` does include the `gatling-jdbc` , so we don't need to extra add it.